# collation issue with unpivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I am getting this error message:

> The type of column "fi_description" conflicts with the type of other
>   columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

```
SELECT fi_contactid, 
       question, 
       answer 
FROM   (SELECT soi.fi_contactid, 
               soi.statuscode, 
               fi_description = soi.fi_description COLLATE database_default, 
               soi.fi_elevationissuecode, 
               soi.fi_identifiedby 
        FROM   ficrm_mscrm.dbo.fi_soiissuebase AS soi WITH (nolock)) p 
       UNPIVOT (question 
               FOR answer IN (statuscode, 
                              fi_description, 
                              fi_elevationissuecode, 
                              fi_identifiedby)) AS unpt
```

fi_contactid  is a **uniqueidentifier**
fi_description is **nvarchar**(255)
fi_elevationissuecode is **int**
fi_identifieby is **uniqueidentifier**

**Is there something I am doing wrong with collation within the unpivot statement?**

Comment: Well, `UNPIVOT` assumes every column in the `IN` has the same data type (or at least, compatible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNPIVOT` will assume the first column in the `IN` list is the datatype of the `FOR` field, and will attempt a direct cast to that type, which may or may not work.

You need to either change the order of your `IN` clause (if a direct cast will work) or cast each column as the same type in your sub query.

Here is any example of a solution:

```
SELECT fi_contactid, 
       question, 
       answer 
FROM   (SELECT soi.fi_contactid, 
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), soi.statuscode) statuscode, 
               fi_description = soi.fi_description COLLATE database_default , 
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), soi.fi_elevationissuecode) fi_elevationissuecode, 
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), soi.fi_identifiedby) fi_identifiedby
        FROM   ficrm_mscrm.dbo.fi_soiissuebase AS soi WITH (nolock)) p 
       UNPIVOT (question 
               FOR answer IN (statuscode, 
                              fi_description, 
                              fi_elevationissuecode, 
                              fi_identifiedby)) AS unpt
```